# Features Vectors to build classifier to detect subjectivity

Tags: nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to build a classifier to detect subjectivity. I have text files tagged with subjective and objective . I am little lost with the concept of features creation from this data. I have found the lexicon of the subjective and objective tag. One thing that I can do is to create a feature of having words present in respective dictionary. Maybe the count of words present in subjective and objective dictionary. After that I intend to use naive bayes or SVM to develop the model

My problem is as follow

1. Is my approach correct ?
2. Can I create more features ? If possible suggest some or point me to some paper or link
3. Can I do some test like chi -sq etc to identify effective words from the dictionary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically on the right track. I would try and apply classifier with features you already have and see how well it will work, before doing anything else.

Actually best way to improve your work is to google for subjectivity classification papers and read them (there are a quite a [number of them](https://scholar.google.ru/scholar?as_ylo=2011&q=subjectivity%20classification&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)). For example [this one](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1312/1312.6962.pdf) lists typical features for this task.

And yes Chi-squared can be used to construct dictionaries for text classification (other commonly used methods are TD*IDF, pointwise mutal information and LDA)

Also, recently new neural network-based methods for text classification such as [paragraph vector](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4053v2.pdf) and [dynamic convolutional neural networks with k-max pooling](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3830v1.pdf) demonstrated state-of-the-art results on sentiment analysis, thus they should probably be good for subjectivity classification as well.

Comment: thanks @denis for pointing me to the right resources and confirming the approach. This will help me a lot